# Dynamically change of JLabel icon

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

There are many similar topics out there, however none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

So, I have an empty `JLabel` and at some time during the execution I want to add an icon on it.

```
String imageLocation = "/home/........" 
jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageLocation));
```

is not working.

Image's location is fine ->

```
System.out.println(new java.io.File(imageLocation).exists());
```

is `true`

Comment: Are you shadowing your variables?  Is the label your interacting with actually on the screen? Are you using `static` references? Would you like me to keep guessing? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `I still can't find any difference between your code and mine` - neither can we because you didn't post your code and we are not mind readers so we can't guess what your code is actually doing.

Comment: *"There are many similar topics out there, however none of the suggested solutions worked for me."* Translation:  "I could not be bothered looking, so just solve this again for me."  What were these similar topics?  Link to them.  Why did the solutions there, not solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Because the icon is a bound property of `JLabel`, `setIcon()` is sufficient, as shown below. Use the example to get your icon location, and see [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) for examples of common problems.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33003415/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        Icon icon = (Icon) UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Test", JLabel.CENTER){

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(2 * icon.getIconWidth(), 2 * icon.getIconHeight());
            }
        };
        f.add(label);
        f.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add icon") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setIcon(icon);
            }
        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: I still can't find any difference between your code and mine (except that you are using an icon from OptionPane). 
You are doing the same thing.
Instantiating an Icon object, and then setting the icon to the JLabel

Comment: @Old-School Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @Old-School: Check permissions along the `imageLocation` path; try copying the icon file to your home or project directory.

Answer (score -1):

you need to revalidate and repaint your label the panel which contain this label , you can do that by the follow :

```
String imageLocation = "/home/........" 
jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageLocation));
//Add this : 
jLabel1.revalidate();
jLabel1.repaint();

//if it does not work try to do the same for the panel which contain this label
```

Comment: remember that you should write image directory like this :  "C:\\Users\\.....\\Desktop\\.myImage.jpg"

Comment: The icon is a bound property; neither `revalidate` nor `repaint` are required.

Comment: i do not know what is the problem , but lets try this : jLabel.setOpaque(true)